# Spreadsheet API - Retrieving a list of spreadsheets

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets

I want to display all spreadsheets of my account ,

I build 2 spreadsheets on my account and try code as below ,

My spreadsheets have been setting public,

But always got nothing ,

```
public class GoogleSheetTest {
    private final static String[] SCOPES_Array = {"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full", "https://docs.google.com/feeds"};
    private final static String SPREADSHEET_URL = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full";
    private final static String SPREADSHEET_ID = "XXXXxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount,com";
  public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, GeneralSecurityException, IOException, ServiceException {
        JacksonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPES_Array);
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                            .setTransport(httpTransport)
                            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                            .setServiceAccountId(SPREADSHEET_ID)
                            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("xxxxxxxx.p12"))
                            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES).build();
        credential.refreshToken();
        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("SpreadSheet_Test");
        service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
        URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(SPREADSHEET_URL);
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,SpreadsheetFeed.class);
        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();
        for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet:spreadsheets){
        System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
    }
}
```

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please describe in more detail the unexpected behaviour, or post error messages or logs.

Comment: No any error messages, just like spreadsheets.size = 0 , but spreadsheets have been build on my account and setting public.

Comment: take the service account email address and share the sheet with it like you would another user.

Comment: It's OK ,very Helpful!!!
Thanks DalmTo :)